# Can't update node: npm does not support Node.js v5.3.0

Tags: node.js, npm

I am using MacOS Sierra v10.12.6, I have written the command `npm update -g` and got the result

```
npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v5.3.0
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 4, 6, 7, 8.
npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
npm ERR! Buffer.alloc is not a function

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/demiryil/.npm/_logs/2017-11-21T08_43_54_258Z-debug.log
```

The logs printed out

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 warn npm npm does not support Node.js v5.3.0
2 warn npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
3 warn npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
4 warn npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 4, 6, 7, 8.
5 warn npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
6 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/Cellar/node/5.3.0/bin/node',
6 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
6 verbose cli   'update',
6 verbose cli   '-g' ]
7 info using npm@5.5.1
8 info using node@v5.3.0
9 verbose stack TypeError: Buffer.alloc is not a function
9 verbose stack     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/lib/pack.js:32:20)
9 verbose stack     at Module._compile (module.js:398:26)
9 verbose stack     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:405:10)
9 verbose stack     at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
9 verbose stack     at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
9 verbose stack     at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
9 verbose stack     at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
9 verbose stack     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/lib/create.js:6:14)
9 verbose stack     at Module._compile (module.js:398:26)
9 verbose stack     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:405:10)
9 verbose stack     at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
9 verbose stack     at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
9 verbose stack     at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
9 verbose stack     at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
9 verbose stack     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/index.js:4:30)
9 verbose stack     at Module._compile (module.js:398:26)
10 verbose cwd /Users/demiryil/Documents/JS projects/katanio
11 verbose Darwin 16.7.0
12 verbose argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/5.3.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "update" "-g"
13 verbose node v5.3.0
14 verbose npm  v5.5.1
15 error Buffer.alloc is not a function
16 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

After searching for a while I found that this command worked for people `sudo npm uninstall -g npm`, however I get the exact same error when trying to uninstall npm.

So how can I update my npm?

Comment: try cleaning cache by "npm cache clean"

Comment: its gives the same error when I try "npm cache clean"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Node.js version `5.3.0` that you are using is severely outdated. You have installed the latest npm version (`5.5.1`), but this is the package manager and it does not run on such an outdated Node.js, because it relies on features that have been added later. As you can see in the error message, it uses [`Buffer.alloc`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_alloc_size_fill_encoding), which did not exist in that version.

You need to upgrade your Node.js (the runtime), not npm (the package manager). When you run `npm update -g` it only updates the packages which have been installed by npm.

It looks like you have installed Node.js with Homebrew, so you can upgrade it with the following commands:

```
brew update
brew upgrade node
```

Comment: Awesome! Worked. I first got errors telling me my xcode version is old, then upgraded my xcode, then got "Xcode alone is not sufficient on Sierra." then I installed "xcode-select --install" and then brew worked fine and now my node is updated.